# Get distinct values from an array using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Does anybody know how to get the distinct values from an array using PHP:

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url_id, time_spent FROM library ORDER BY url_id
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php ?

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure which you want to do, the "distinct" should do it along with a group by in SQL.

But, if you want to somehow go through the data afterwards use array_unique.

Your question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).